# using Karate to match parts of response

Tags: karate

I have response that may have recursive objects like this:

```
"categoriesArray": [
  {
    "id": "category1",
    "href": "/categories/categoryId/category1",
    "name": "category name 1",

    "categoriesArray": [
      {
        "id": "category2",
        "href": "/categories/categoryId/category2",
        "name": "category name 2",
        }
    ]
    }
]
```

I want match all ids in order like this :

- def category1 = {id:'category1'}
- def category2 = {id:'category2'}
  And match response[0].categoriesArray contains category1
  And match response[0].categoriesArray[0].categoriesArray contains category2

So there's a shortcut like appendRoot("response[0].categoriesArray[0].categoriesArray") in RestAssured to go deeper without repeating the path?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with JsonPath, you have pretty smart options. I think this will work for you:

```
* def response =
"""
{
  "categoriesArray": [
    {
      "id": "category1",
      "href": "/categories/categoryId/category1",
      "name": "category name 1",
      "categoriesArray": [
        {
          "id": "category2",
          "href": "/categories/categoryId/category2",
          "name": "category name 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
"""
* match response..id contains ['category1', 'category2']
* def cat1 = response.categoriesArray[0]
* match cat1..id contains 'category2'
* match response.categoriesArray[?(@.id=='category1')].categoriesArray..id contains 'category2'
```

EDIT: added more options in response to comment

Comment: But this doesn't check that category2 is inside category1, than I must do another match.

Comment: @Charles I edited my answer. there are many many possibilities. read the docs on `match` and jsonPath. you can even do this in java code or by using the `karate.filter()` api. if this does not answer the question, kindly provide an example of REST-assured and show how it is easier. thanks.

Comment: With restassured I could do 
`response.body("categoriesArray.find{it.id==category1}",notNullValue())
  .appendRoot("categoriesArray.find{it.id==category1}.categoriesArray")
  .body("find{it.id==category2}",notNullValue())`

I agree that jsonPath has very good options, but when you go deeper inside json it's good to a shortcut.

Comment: @Charles lol. I can't understand this, so I give up. one more suggestion, please read the docs for `match each` and pay attention to the `$` and `_$` built-in variables. maybe that is exactly what you need.